# Need to update only particular element in an array of mongo in java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, filter

I want to update a particular element in an array of mongo with filters.

I have already tried having using `BasicDBObject`, but than not able to use filter as i have collection of type `MongoCollection`.

```
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection(tnId);
```

Even tried:

```
FindIterable<Document> document = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("DocumentName", documentName)                       .append("Attributes.name", "Party 1" ).append("Attributes.value", 12)                   .append("Attributes.actualValue.initialValue", USA));
```

But in this case What I get is the whole record and than I have to iterate through each Attribute again.

```
mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase(companyName);
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection(tnId);
```

Actual data which I am passing is

```
{
    "DocumentName" : "doc1",
    "Attributes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Party 1",
            "value" : 12,
            "actualValue" : {
                "initialValue" : "USA"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Party 1",
            "value" : 16,
            "actualValue" : {
                "initialValue" : "SYSTEM"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to search attribute where actualValue is "USA" and Value of attribute is 12 and updated data should look like

```
{
    "DocumentName" : "doc1",
    "Attributes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Party 1",
            "value" : 12,
            "actualValue" : {
                "initialValue" : "USA"
            },
            "updatedvalue" : {
                "initialValue" : "USA",
                "changedValue" : "Europe"
             }

        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Party 1",
            "value" : 16,
            "actualValue" : {
                "initialValue" : "SYSTEM"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ "Attributes.actualValue.initialValue": "USA" }, 
  { $set: { "Attributes.$.updatedvalue.initialValue": "USA",      "Attributes.$.updatedvalue.changedValue": "Europe" } })
```

db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ "Attributes.actualValue.initialValue": "USA" }, 
{ $set: { "Attributes.$.updatedvalue.initialValue": "India", "Attributes.$.updatedvalue.changedValue": "India" } })

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
db.collection.updateMany(
 { "Attributes.actualValue.initialValue": "USA" },
 { $set: { "Attributes.$.updatedvalue" : {
            "initialValue" : "USA",
            "changedValue" : "Europe"
         } } }
)
```

Comment: I want filter on the basis of name,value and actualValue.initialValue all 3. As my data can be repeated.Once I get data than update only that data. And how would I write it in Java.I want something like ```Bson updateDocument = new Document("$set", d);
collection.updateOne(filter, updateDocument);``` SO how to write a filter?

Answer (score 0):

How I did is. I made a document where i added teh required data which i want to update it with.Say

```
Document valueDocument = new Document();

valueDocument.put("InitialValue", USA);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("Attributes", att);

BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
data.put("Attributes.$.updatedvalue" + qCLevel, valueDocument);

BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
command.put("$set", data);
collection.updateOne(query, command);
```

It goes and insert the data in the right place.